# Gradle with CMake Issue with git_describe

Tags: android, git, gradle, cmake

I did run into issue with running gradle with cmake.

This part of the code inside cmake file does not seem to work correctly

`git_describe(GIT_DESCRIBE "--abbrev=7")`

Because there is part of the code that depends on defined `GIT_DESCRIBE` and because `git_describe` fails block of that code does not gets execute. And I want to make it work as expected thus executing this block of code.

Here is the scheme of the Project:

```
-Root Dir of the Project:
  -Submodule of git repo
  -Rest of the files
```

Gradle File where it does set the Cmake (CMakeLists is contained inside of that submodule)

```
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                path 'path/to/CMakeLists.txt'
            }
        }
```

It should work out of the box but when using this combination `gradle + cmake` it fails.

Running `git describe  --abbrev=7` in terminal shows the expected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced `git_describe` with `execute_process`

```
execute_process(COMMAND git describe --abbrev=7
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_DESCRIBE)
```

This solved issue.